# what number row does 'x' appear on

Tags: python, pandas

Morning,

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df

     Code
 0   F5031032
 1   F5546810
 2   F117225534
 3   F17770
 4   F29157
```

I want to be able to find out what row two of the codes sits on. So the answer i am looking for would be:

```
Code       Row
F5031032   1
F17770     4
```

thanks

Comment: I think, I'm missing something, but is it just `df['Row'] = df.index + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
codes = ["F5031032", "F5546810", "F117225534", "F17770", "F29157"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=codes, columns=['Code'])
df['Row'] = df.index+1
print df
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for select values, then get index to `idx` and if index not start from `0`, use [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
print df
         Code
2    F5031032
3    F5546810
4  F117225534
5      F17770
6      F29157

print df['Code'].isin(['F5031032','F17770'])
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
Name: Code, dtype: bool

idx = df[df['Code'].isin(['F5031032','F17770'])].index
print idx
Int64Index([2, 5], dtype='int64')

print df.index.get_indexer(idx)
[0 3]

df1 = df[df['Code'].isin(['F5031032','F17770'])].copy()
df1['Row'] = df.index.get_indexer(idx) + 1
print df1
       Code  Row
2  F5031032    1
5    F17770    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for something like this

```
In [10]: df_filter = df[df['Code'].isin(['F5031032', 'F17770'])]

In [11]: df_filter['Row'] = df_filter.index + 1


In [12]: df_filter
Out[12]: 
       Code  Row
0  F5031032    1
3    F17770    4
```